# Is there anyway to call multiple end statement

Tags: ruby, ruby-3

Is there anyway to call multiple end statement

Like I have a for loop and an if-else statement so can I do two ends together like `end[2]` or `end*2`

My statement is: `a.each do |i| if i<0 then l+=1 elsif i>0 then s+=1 else h+=1 end end`
Here you can see there are two end statements can I turn them into one and shorten the code.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: Why do you need such a one-liner? You can use curly braces with `each` like this `a.each { |i| here_your_code }`.

Comment: I wanted to solve the problem is shortest code

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is an "end statement"? There is no such thing as an "end  statement" in Ruby. In fact, there are no statements *at all* in Ruby. And what does it mean to "call" an end statement? You cannot call statements in Ruby. Actually, you cannot really call anything in Ruby, you can only send a message, and Ruby will call a method for you.

Comment: Sir may I know what is it called then, Because I am very new to ruby

Answer (score 0):

> can I do two ends together like `end[2]` or `end*2`

No, there isn't such syntax.

But you could rewrite your code in other ways, e.g. via [`<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Integer.html#3C-3D-3E-method) and [`tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#tally-method):

```
a = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]

counts = a.map { |i| i <=> 0 }.tally

l, s, h = counts.values_at(-1, 0, 1)

l #=> 2
s #=> 3
h #=> 1
```

Comment: Thx 
What does the count.values and .tally do

Comment: @SaadYarKhan have a look at the docs. `tally` returns the number of occurrences as a hash and `values_at` fetches the values for `-1`, `0`, and `1` which correspond to negative, zero and positive numbers.